# Clustering Method Comparison : Hierarchical vs Latent Class Analysis in R programming

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am applying hclust for hierarchical clustering in R and poLCA for latent class analysis on a data set.
I need to make a comparison on both clustering method analysis by numerical and pictorial representation.

Can someone suggest the method to check homogeneity and heterogeneity of above clustering methods?

Comment: Can anyone please suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called clValid that may help you.

Here is the paper:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clValid/vignettes/clValid.pdf

Here is the r documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clValid/clValid.pdf

Comment: I have checked clValid function it can be used for  "hierarchical","kmeans","pam" but not for poLCA.
I am looking for something that can be used to compare hierarchical and LCA clustering method